# Can't get any jquery lightbox to work

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto, lightbox2

UPDATE: Now lightbox and easybox are both working for the wordpress gallery, the problem was the a links were referring to the image attachment page and not the image itself. Now that I have solved it both easybox and lightbox are working. **Problem:** Still not able to get swipebox and prettyphoto to work. I don't know where to place the activation script. $('.swipebox').swipebox(); Would really appreciate your help.

I am trying to install a jquery lightbox for a wordpress theme gallery. I tried Lightbox2, easybox, swipebox and in all I followed the steps as mentioned on the respective websites. I included all the js and css files. Put the required code everywhere in the  - differently in each case depending on what plugin is being used and according to the instructions provided. e.g in case of swipebox:

```
$(".gallery a").each(function () {$(this).attr("class", "swipebox");});
$(".swipebox").swipebox();
```

(I have tried adding this code in an already included js file, or separately as a script in header, or in footer, nothing happens, even when all swipebox files are being included)

The problem with Lightbox2 - the overlay appears but the image does not load in the lightbox overlay and just keeps waiting for hours to load. Click on any image in the gallery, it takes forever to load.

All others - The gallery item when clicked on opens in another page as if the lightbox plugin doesn't exist, even when I can see all the js and css files included properly in the inspect element->sources window.
 I would prefer using swipebox or easybox so please help!

**Update:**
I tried prettyPhoto as well. This is how I went ahead (I have done similarly in all other plugins):

The code to include files for a plugin goes as follows in a separate php file:

```
<?php
```

function gs_lightbox(){
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'lightboxcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/prettyphoto/css/prettyPhoto.css' );

}
```

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'gs_lightbox');?>

In my functions.php I call this file, and all files are therefore being included when I check the Inspect Element->Source.

```
//Include Lightbox
```

include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/prettyPhoto/includept.php');

In my js scripts file I add this code to activate the plugin:

```
$(".gallery a").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("rel", "prettyPhoto");
});
```

All a tags are being added with the rel attribute:

Shouldn't this work? But its not, when I click the gallery Image,it still opens in a new page...I have no idea what is going wrong here, Please help!

Comment: You could use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/), instead of `attr`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding the `.swipebox` class in a script instead of outputting it as part of your HTML?

Comment: FYI you can use `$(".gallery a").addClass('swipebox');` to addClass to all elements .

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: I added the script as part of HTML header or footer also. But please share how to do that correctly.

Comment: Many thanks to all for replying!

Comment: Yay! Got easybox to work!! will try others too!